# Doing a search for words out of order

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a search box on my application to query the titles of books (amongst other things) and want to be able to search a title with the words out of order: example: being able to get a record back even if Huckleberry Finn was searched as Finn Huckleberry.  I've looked into full text search but it is getting too complicated as I want to make queries across multiple joined tables.  As a get-around, is it too strange if I use php to break up the words where there are spaces, store the words as an array, and do a loop of WHERE title LIKE "%'.$titlekeyword.'%" for the array?

or is that just a mess waiting to happen?  I don't want to do anything too strange with my application as someone will be taking over it

Comment: You could `explode` the title keywords on a space and check each word: `WHERE title LIKE '%Finn%' AND/OR title LIKE '%Huckleberry%'`.

Comment: I think it's better to apply some `autocomplete` on user input, e.g. [jQuery.autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generate query like

```
 SELECT ... WHERE title like '%Finn%' AND title '%Huckleberry%' AND title '%next%'

implode(' AND ',array_map(function($x){
    return '`title` like "%'.$x.'%"';
},explode(' ',$str)));
```

Comment: each title in the above should have like next to it (huckleberry and next are missing).